# how can I do the validation of a form with javascript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm new here at Stack Overflow an I'm also a beginner in programming so please have mercy :)
I'm trying to block with javascript the submission of a multi field form when one or more fields are empty.
Basically, when I submit the form leaving all the fields blank, the error appears only below the first field but nothing happens to the others and the form is sent.
I do apologize in advance as this topic has already been treated several times in other threads but I can't figure out how to make in work.
I'm using the following code (html and js in the same page):

```css
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm() {
 var a = document.forms["form1"]["nome"].value;
    var b = document.forms["form1"]["cognome"].value; 
 var c = document.forms["form1"]["azienda"].value; 
 var d = document.forms["form1"]["CF"].value; 
 var e = document.forms["form1"]["msg"].value; 
 
 if (a == ""){
  document.getElementById('err_nome').innerHTML += "Il nome è obbligatorio";
  return false;}

 if (b == ""){
  document.getElementById('err_cognome').innerHTML += "Il cognome è obbligatorio";
  return false;}

 if (c == ""){
  document.getElementById('err_azienda').innerHTML += "Il azienda è obbligatorio";
  return false;}

 if (d == ""){
  document.getElementById('err_CF').innerHTML += "Il CF è obbligatorio";
  return false;}

 if (e == ""){
  document.getElementById('err_msg').innerHTML += "Il msg è obbligatorio";
  return false;}
}

</script>
```

```html
<html>

<body>
<?php include ("incl/header.php"); ?>

<div class="menu">
<?php include ("incl/menu.php") ?>
</div>

<div class="column-left">
</div>

<div class="column-center"><br>

<form name="form1" method="post" action="sendmail.php" onsubmit="validateForm()>
<br>

Nome
<input type="text" name="nome">*
<br><span class="error"><div id="err_nome"></div></span><br><br><br>

Cognome
<input type="text" name="cognome">*
<br><span class="error"><div id="err_cognome"></div></span><br><br><br>

Azienda
<input type="text" name="azienda">*
<br><span class="error"><div id="err_azienda"></div></span><br><br><br>

Codice Fiscale
<input type="text" name="CF">*
<br><span class="error"><div id="err_CF"></div></span><br><br><br>

Messaggio
<textarea id="text" name="msg" rows="5" col="40" maxlength="2000"></textarea>*
<br><span class="error"><div id="err_msg"></div></span><br>

<br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
</form>

</div>

<div class="column-right">
</div>

<div class="footer">
<?php include "incl/footer.php"; ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks to those of you will help.
Alberto

Comment: You have `return false;` in all your comparisons, that will exit the `validateForm()` function after the first incorrect field. If you want to validate all fields, keep the result in variable and return it at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `return false;` in all your comparisons, that will exit the `validateForm()` function after the first incorrect field. If you want to validate all fields, keep the result in variable and return it at the end. Like this:

```js
function validateForm() {
  var a = document.forms["form1"]["nome"].value;
  var b = document.forms["form1"]["cognome"].value;
  var c = document.forms["form1"]["azienda"].value;
  var d = document.forms["form1"]["CF"].value;
  var e = document.forms["form1"]["msg"].value;
  var result = true;

  if (a == "") {
    document.getElementById('err_nome').innerHTML += "Il nome è obbligatorio";
    result = result && false;
  }

  if (b == "") {
    document.getElementById('err_cognome').innerHTML += "Il cognome è obbligatorio";
    result = result && false;
  }

  if (c == "") {
    document.getElementById('err_azienda').innerHTML += "Il azienda è obbligatorio";
    result = result && false;
  }

  if (d == "") {
    document.getElementById('err_CF').innerHTML += "Il CF è obbligatorio";
    result = result && false;
  }

  if (e == "") {
    document.getElementById('err_msg').innerHTML += "Il msg è obbligatorio";
    result = result && false;
  }
  
  return result
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>


  <div class="menu">

  </div>

  <div class="column-left">
  </div>

  <div class="column-center"><br>

    <form name="form1" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <br> Nome
      <input type="text" name="nome">*
      <br><span class="error"><div id="err_nome"></div></span><br><br><br> Cognome
      <input type="text" name="cognome">*
      <br><span class="error"><div id="err_cognome"></div></span><br><br><br> Azienda
      <input type="text" name="azienda">*
      <br><span class="error"><div id="err_azienda"></div></span><br><br><br> Codice Fiscale
      <input type="text" name="CF">*
      <br><span class="error"><div id="err_CF"></div></span><br><br><br> Messaggio
      <textarea id="text" name="msg" rows="5" col="40" maxlength="2000"></textarea>*
      <br><span class="error"><div id="err_msg"></div></span><br>

      <br>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
      <br><br><br><br><br><br>
    </form>

  </div>

  <div class="column-right">
  </div>

  <div class="footer">

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```